# Java NextBoolean() read from text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, mismatch

Hey guys im getting these errors when trying to read from a text file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at application.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

From  trying to work out what the problem is I think its the `nextBoolean()` as when I remove this I dont get any errors.

Here's my code:

```
package application;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int age = 0;
            String type = null, name = null, breed = null, desc = null;
            boolean male = false;

            File file = new File("animals.txt");
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(file);

            while (kb.hasNext()) {

                age = kb.nextInt();
                kb.nextLine();
                type = kb.nextLine();
                male = kb.nextBoolean();
                name = kb.nextLine();
                breed = kb.nextLine();
                desc = kb.nextLine();

                Animal animal = new Animal(age, type, male, name, breed, desc);

                AnimalList.add(animal);

            }
            AnimalList.printAnimalList();
            kb.close();
        } 


    }
```

Here's the text file contents

```
6
Dog
false
Fred
Jack Rusell
dog is in poor condition
5
Cat
false
James
Russian blue
Good
9
Cat
true
Felix
Tabby
Cat in good condition
4
Bird
true
chirpy
Parrot
Parrot in good condition
```

I would be grateful for any help. I've been googling for the past few hours and I can't find any explanation.

Comment: You might try printing out what you are reading at each `next...()` call, so you can if your input lines up the way you intend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a call to `nextLine` after `nextBoolean`.

The `nextBoolean` and `nextInt` method won't read the lineFeed of your line, it will stop right away after reading the `boolean` or `int`.

You retrieve the `name` directly by calling `nextLine` and you expect "Fred" but instead get an empty string because you are still on the same line. "Fred" will actually be assigned to `breed` and your reading is corrupted.

Comment: thanks this didnt work earlier but did when i tried again after ur recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You should add line `kb.nextLine();` after `male = kb.nextBoolean();` to enforce `Scanner` to go to the next line.

Otherwise `name` has a value after boolean value in the **same** line (it's empty) and all other values are read with a shift.

Comment: thanks i tried that earlier as i thought it may have something to do with the new char line and it didnt work. i just tried it again and it worked. wtf anyway thanks a lot. i was going to blow my brains out if it took any longer